# XML tag exist or not?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

How to check if xml tag exist in C #?
My Xml

```
<name>
  <firstname>John</firstname> 
  <lastname>cena</lastname> 
  <job>Administrator</job> 
  <location>sunnyvale</location> 
  <age>19</age> 
</name>

<name>
  <firstname>mark</firstname> 
  <job>Agent</job> 
  <location>Bangalore</location> 
  <age>22</age> 
</name>
```

lastname tag doesn't exist for mark how to check in C#?

Comment: What kind of answer do you want?  Just true/false or a list of name elements w/o lastname?

Comment: You need to be more clear about your question..? I agree with Henk Holtermann..

Comment: Answer for the above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string xml = @"
    <name>
        <firstname>mark</firstname> 
        <job>Agent</job> 
        <location>Bangalore</location> 
        <age>22</age> 
    </name>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
bool isLastNameExists = doc.Descendants("name").Elements("lastname").Any();
```

Comment: int nodelastname = SIElement.GetElementsByTagName("lastname").Count;

                if (nodelastname == 0)
                {
                    nodelastname = 'NA';
                }
                else
                {
                    string lastname = SIElement.GetElementsByTagName("lastname")[0].InnerText;
    }